# Saving ajax POST data with PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I've been trying to save some data to a .json file with ajax and php.
At the moment I'm receiving an error and my data is not being saved and can't figure out why.

This is my .js file:

```
var data = {
    "test": "helloworld"
}
    $.ajax({
    url: "save.php",
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#saved").text("Data has been saved.");},
    error: function (data){
        $("#saved").text("Failed to save data !");}
    });
```

And here is my php file:

```
    $json = $_POST['data'];
    if(json_decode($json) != null){
      $file = fopen('web/js/data_save.json', 'w+');
      fwrite($file, json_encode($json));
      fclose($file);
    }else{
        print("<pre>Error saving data !</pre>");
    }
```

When I'm trying to save the ajax error is getting triggered:

```
     error: function (data){
 $("#saved").text("Failed to save data !");
     }
```

I hope someone can guide me in the right direction :)

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify(data)`

Comment: If jQuery triggers your error callback, then your request obviously fails somehow. Best you check with the developer tools (inspector, firebug etc.) what requests are being sent and what response you get from the server.

Comment: @Sumurai, if you read the post you would have noticed:

Answer (score 1):

this works fine for me

.js:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    var json_object = {"data": "helloworld"};

    $.ajax({
        url: "../tests/save.php",
        data: json_object,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(json_object) {
            console.log(json_object);
            $("#saved").text("Data has been saved.");
        },
        error: function(json_object) {
            console.log(json_object);
            $("#saved").text("Failed to save data !");
        }
    });
});
```

.php

```
$post_data = $_POST['data'];
if (!empty($post_data)) {
    $file = fopen('data_save.json', 'w+');
    fwrite($file, json_encode($post_data));
    fclose($file);
    echo json_encode('success');
}
```

if you do a var_dump on the $_POST you ll see that your variable is sent as an array in php. also you need to echo a json string for the callback success

Comment: Thank you it worked now, so my issue was my variable it should have been $_POST['test']; Thanks a dozen for helping out and also the console.log is nice to have ! :)

Answer (score -1):

You do not have any key `data` in your request.
You need to parse the whole request body as JSON with [`http_get_request_body`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-get-request-body.php) or something to get the raw body in order to get the result you want.

EDIT: As it seems that there has been some confusion, here are some further explanations.

When sending a JSON POST request to PHP, you **cannot** use the `$_POST` variable as you would with a normal request.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"foo": "bar"}' myhost/foo.php
```

with foo.php defined as bellow will print an empty array, try it yourself if you want.

```
<?php
print_r($_POST);
```

When you need to get JSON from the body of the POST request, you need to get **all the body**, and then parse it from JSON.
You can do this in several ways, one of which being the one I wrote before editing. 
You can also get the whole body without using any extension by using

```
file_get_contents('php://input')
```

The result should be the same.

So with the code bellow you should get what you want.

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
print_r($json);
```

Comment: The first thing the code example does is create an object called `data`.  This is then passed as the data property of the ajax call, so it *is* passed to the php script as post data, which is how it refers to it.  What are you saying is wrong with that?

Comment: Where is the object called `data` ?

Comment: It's the very 1st line of code - `var data = {...` or, in the 1st line of php - `$json = $_POST['data'];`

Comment: PHP does not care what is the name of the variable in JS. $_POST['data'] will not contain anything.

Comment: Archer, you are wrong. He has $_POST['test'], no $_POST['data']

Comment: My bad - of course he would need `$json = $_POST['test'];`.  Why don't you put that in your answer?

Comment: Yeah, I just posted that :p

Comment: I do not think `$_POST['test']` will contain anything either, unless PHP became smart enough to parse the request body with the content type given or something like this.

Comment: That just shows how little I know about php then.  I assumed it worked the same as ASP.Net where you could get the value of test on the server with `Request.Form["test"]`.  I think I'll stick to what I know ;)

Comment: Some framework will do this for you in PHP too, but raw PHP will not handle anything else than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.
If you could please take off the downvote by the way.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still not convinced.  Where does he specify that the data object is sent as JSON?  By default jQuery's ajax call would convert the data object to `test=helloworld` and post it, unless he specifies the `contentType` which he hasn't done.

Comment: Ok sorry, I was more or less convinced (from the title of the question) that the author was trying to send some JSON data to the server. If this is not the case, you are prefectly right.

Comment: I seriously thought I should give up coding as I couldn't see where the problem was!  Thanks for clearing that up for me :)  And yes, unclear question is unclear.